# java.lang.NullPointerException when using webdriver manager selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

While using selenium with java, WebdriverManager is not running and the below code is giving `null pointer exception`. I have returned the driver at end of class.

I have one ask whether should I keep the Webdriver driver as static or not.

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Browserselector {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public static Properties prop;

    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {

        {

            String browserName = "firefox";
            System.out.println(browserName);

            if (browserName.contains("Chrome")) {
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();

            } else if (browserName.contains("IE")) {
                WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();

                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            } else if (browserName.contains("FireFox")) {
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            } else if (browserName.contains("EDGE")) {
                WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
                driver = new EdgeDriver();

            }
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("google.com");
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to start "firefox" - but the if condition checks for "Firefox", if you want to use it like that change the following condition

```
browserName.contains("FireFox")
```

into

```
browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("FireFox")
```

I recommend you to change the nested if  with a "switch" it's more readable and easy to follow/understand

Also, don't use a URL without specifying the protocol

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```